# Display three letters time zone code using jsTimezoneDetect script

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timezone, jstimezonedetect

I am using [jsTimezoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/overview) script to detect user current timezone. Code below display result as `America/Chicago`. Is there a way to display `CDT`/`CST` (depending on today date)?

```
var timezone = jstz.determine();
timezone.name();
```

Or is there any other script I can use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First understand:

- A time zone abbreviation is potentially ambiguous (5 different CST's).
- Not all time zones have meaningful abbreviations.  Some are just made up to complete the API, but not actually used by people in the region  (MSK in Belarus).
- There are often disagreements about the correct abbreviation to use  (HST vs HAST).
- They are usually in English, though other languages may have different abbreviations for the same time zone.  (PST vs HNP (French))
- The abbreviation depends highly on the specific date chosen - as it could change for daylight saving time  (EST vs EDT).

In many browsers, you can get the abbreviation directly (via [ECMA-402](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/)) by:

```js
const d = new Date(); // now, or the specific date in question
const tz = d.toLocaleString('en', {timeZoneName: 'short'}).split(' ').pop();
console.log(tz);
```

This doesn't necessarily work everywhere though.

Since you're working with jsTimeZoneDetect, you already have an IANA time zone identifier ("America/Chicago").  So, you could get it from [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), like this:

```
var m = moment(); // now, or the moment in question
var s = m.tz('America/Chicago').format('z');
```

That will work everywhere, but you have the overhead of moment and moment-timezone, and jstz, which is probably overkill unless you are using these libraries for other purposes anyway.

You might also consider a server-side solution.  For example, if you're using PHP, you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12939002/634824).  Or, if you're using .NET, you can use my [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) library.

Comment: Under the hood it uses `zoneAbbr()` so, you could do something like `const abbrTz = moment.tz('America/Chicago').zoneAbbr();` to get the abbreviated Time Zone. Additionally, if you want `moment` to guess the user's/browser's local Time Zone then you could do something like this: `const abbrLocalTz = moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).zoneAbbr();` note that `guess()` is a method off the `tz` property object not the `tz()` method.

Answer (score -2):

In native JS you could:

> var d = new Date();
>   timezone = d.getTimezoneOffset();

and then go over it with a switch.

Comment: Many time zones use the same offset.  One cannot determine a time zone or abbreviation by offset alone.  See [this list on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) for examples.

Comment: perhaps, but i doubt that it will affect someone regionally.   In my case, we only deal with four time zones so a case statement is conceivably a solution.